# Im trying to create a calculator program but the errors are confusing me

Tags: python-3.x

I tried doing addition and it worked but a trig function did not work, I think i need more code for the display function but im not sure

```
from guizero import *
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
screen = ""

#clear everything
def clear():
    global numbers, operations, screen
    screen = ""
    display.value = screen

#delete last input
def delete():
    global screen
    try:
        screen = screen[0:len(screen)-1]
        display.value = screen
    except:
        pass
#Calculate the result
def performCalculation(num1, operator, num2):
    if operator == "+":
        answer = float(num1) + float(num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        answer = float(num1) - float(num2)
    elif operator == "x":
        answer = float(num1) * float(num2)
    elif operator == "÷":
        if (num2 == "0"):
            return "cannot divide by zero"
        answer = float(num1) / float(num2)
    elif operator == "sinh()":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.sinh(float(num2)))
    elif operator == "sin()":
        answer = float(num1) *(np.sin(float(num2)))
        answer=round(answer,5)
    elif operator == "cos()":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.cos(float(num2)))
    elif operator == "tan()":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.tan(float(num2)))
    elif operator == "ln()":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.log(float(num2)))
    elif operator == "arccos":
        if num2 >= 1 or num2 <= -1:
            answer = float(num1) * (np.arccos(float(num2)))
        else:
            return "answer should be between 1 and -1"
    elif operator == "arcsine":
        if num2 >= 1 or num2 <= -1:
            answer = float(num1) * (np.arcsin(float(num2)))
        else:
            return "answer should be between 1 and -1"        
    elif operator == "arctan":
        if num2 >= 1 or num2 <= -1:
            answer = float(num1) * (np.arctan(float(num2)))
        else:
            return "answer should be between 1 and -1"       
    elif operator == "x^x":
        try:
            answer = float(num1) ** float(num2)
        except OverflowError:
            return "operation too large"
    elif operator == "√":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.sqrt(float(num2)))
    elif operator == "log()":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.log10(float(num2)))
    elif operator == "cosh()":
        answer = float(num1) * (np.cosh(float(num2)))  
    else:
        return "an unknown error has occured"
    
    return answer
def calculate():
    global numbers, operations, screen, errors
    operators = ["+", "-", "x", "÷", "cos()","tan()","sin()","sinh()","arcsin()","arccos()","arctan()","ln()","x^x","cosh()","√","log()"]
    hold = []

    until = len(screen)
    i = 0

    if display.value in errors:
        clear()
        return



    while len(screen) != 1 or screen[len(screen)-1] not in operators:
        #split current input into items to be calculated
        if screen[i] in operators and i > 0:
            operator = screen[i]
            vals = screen.split(operator)
            number = vals[0]
            hold.append(number)
            hold.append(operator)
            screen = vals[1]
            hold.append(screen)
            break
            
        else:
            i += 1

        if len(screen) == 1:
            hold.append(screen)

    


    #get result
    display.value = performCalculation(hold[0], hold[1], hold[2])
    screen = display.value
    
    

#Displays current input to the screen, a button press at a time
def screenCapture(obj):
    global screen, display, errors
    if display.value in errors:
        clear()
    obj = str(obj)
    screen += obj
    display.value = screen


#errors
errors = ["Division By Zero Error", "Overflow Error"]


#calculator gui
calculator = App("calculator",height=500,width=550)
#number buttons
numberkeys=Box(calculator,border=True,layout="grid",align="left")
one=PushButton(numberkeys,text="1",command=lambda:screenCapture(1),grid=[0,0])
two=PushButton(numberkeys,text="2",command=lambda:screenCapture(2),grid=[1,0])
three=PushButton(numberkeys,text="3",command=lambda:screenCapture(3),grid=[2,0])
four=PushButton(numberkeys,text="4",command=lambda:screenCapture(4),grid=[0,1])
five=PushButton(numberkeys,text="5",command=lambda:screenCapture(5),grid=[1,1])
six=PushButton(numberkeys,text="6",command=lambda:screenCapture(6),grid=[2,1])
seven=PushButton(numberkeys,text="7",command=lambda:screenCapture(7),grid=[0,2])
eight=PushButton(numberkeys,text="8",command=lambda:screenCapture(8),grid=[1,2])
nine=PushButton(numberkeys,text="9",command=lambda:screenCapture(9),grid=[2,2])
zero=PushButton(numberkeys,text="0",command=lambda:screenCapture(0),grid=[1,3])
equals = PushButton(numberkeys, text="=", command=calculate, grid=[0,3])
decimal=PushButton(numberkeys,text=".",command=lambda:screenCapture("."),grid=[2,3])
#display
displayBox = Box(calculator, border=True, height=40, width=550,align="top")
display = Text(displayBox)
#operator buttons
operatorbox=Box(calculator,border=True,layout="grid",align="right")
add=PushButton(operatorbox,text="   +   ",command=lambda:screenCapture("+"),grid=[0,0])
minus=PushButton(operatorbox,text="       -        ",command=lambda:screenCapture("-"),grid=[1,0])
divide=PushButton(operatorbox,text="      /       ",command=lambda:screenCapture("/"),grid=[2,0])
multiply=PushButton(operatorbox,text="      *     ",command=lambda:screenCapture("*"),grid=[3,0])
cosine=PushButton(operatorbox,text="cos()",command=lambda:screenCapture("cos()"),grid=[0,1])
tan=PushButton(operatorbox,text="tan()",command=lambda:screenCapture("tan()"),grid=[0,2])
sine=PushButton(operatorbox,text="sin()",command=lambda:screenCapture("sin()"),grid=[0,3])
sinh=PushButton(operatorbox,text="sinh()",command=lambda:screenCapture("sinh()"),grid=[2,1])
arcsine=PushButton(operatorbox,text="  arcsine  ",command=lambda:screenCapture("arcsine"),grid=[1,2])
arccos=PushButton(operatorbox,text="   arccos  ",command=lambda:screenCapture("arccos"),grid=[1,3])
arctan=PushButton(operatorbox,text="  arctan  ",command=lambda:screenCapture("arctan"),grid=[1,1])
naturallog=PushButton(operatorbox,text="    ln()    ",command=lambda:screenCapture("ln()"),grid=[2,2])
to_power=PushButton(operatorbox,text="    x^x    ",command=lambda:screenCapture("x^x"),grid=[2,3])
cosh=PushButton(operatorbox,text="cosh()",command=lambda:screenCapture("cosh()"),grid=[3,1])
squareroot=PushButton(operatorbox,text="    √     ",command=lambda:screenCapture("√"),grid=[3,2])
log10=PushButton(operatorbox,text="  log()  ",command=lambda:screenCapture("log()"),grid=[3,3])



methodBox = Box(calculator, layout="grid", align="bottom", height=100,width=150)
clear = PushButton(methodBox, text="CLEAR", command=clear, grid=[0,0])
delete = PushButton(methodBox, text="DEL", command=delete, grid=[2,0])

calculator.display()
```

can someone help me distinguish the error  line 89, in calculate
if screen[i] in operators and i > 0:
IndexError: string index out of range

i tried it multiple times and i got errors IndexError: string index out of range.
im an intermediate programmer but need some help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Distinguish what error? you need to indicate what errors you are receiving and and what your expected output is instead.  Please check the [ask] page for more tips on how to improve this question

Comment: i entered more information about the error, thanks